# Beloved of somebody

Tags: adjectives, passive-voice, past-participles

> **OF**
> 19. **By**: *beloved of the family*.
>
> https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=of

What Part of Speech is *beloved* here then? What's its pronunciation?

Comment: [[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/beloved)] correctly gives 'beloved of' as a colligation, a grammatically required form (contrast collocation / compound) best considered inseparable. _beloved of = loved by_. The pronunciation of the fossilised string _has_ however been modernised, the two-syllable rendering of 'beloved' being favoured by many in this usage.

Comment: However, "many" favouring the pronunciation "belov'd" doesn't stop many favouring "belovèd" instead. Both pronunciations are fine.